# How do I install Skype Integration to Debian 8.4?

Tags: debian, gnome-shell, skype

I am on Debian 8.4 and want to install Skype integration for GNOME which I found here: [Skype integration for GNOME](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/696/skype-integration/) But, I am getting an error.

1. Click on the switch ("OFF" => "ON")

[image]

2. Click on the install button

[image]

3. ERROR!?

[image]

Comment: I created a bug issue at https://github.com/chrisss404/gnome-shell-ext-SkypeNotification/issues/65 , it might related even though our gnome shell version is difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fresh installed Debian 8.4 x64 with only GNOME. Then I have installed Skype on it. Logged in with Microsoft account. And when I open the page in Firefox and click on the button, Skype plainly asks to allow the action, then it restarts itself and immediately after that that, it works. Note that it works only with the "latest" version available 4.3.

[image: polite question]

[image: and voila]